# What is a geometric example of the second isomorphism theorem in ring theory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

All examples of the second isomorphism theorem have been motivated by elementary number theory. What are some informative examples which are motivated by algebraic geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the morphism of algebras
$$
S = \mathbb{Z}[t] \to \mathbb{Z}[t,x,y] \to \mathbb{Z}[t,x,y]/(p,xy-t,t^5-1) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p[xy-t,t^5 - 1] = R
$$
then, the image of this morphism is isomorphic the ring
$$
\mathbb{Z}/p[t]/(t^5-1)
$$
If we look at this geometrically, then the image of $S$
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Spec}\left( \mathbb{Z}/p[t]/(t^5 - 1) \right) & \to & \text{Spec}\left( \mathbb{Z}/p[t,x,y]/(xy-t,t^5 - 1) \right)\\
& & \downarrow \\
& & \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{Z}
\end{matrix}
$$
is a finite set of points in the curve $\text{Spec}\left( \mathbb{Z}/p[t,x,y]/(xy-t,t^5 - 1) \right)$

Comment: @MooS I think your idea of what algebraic geometry is, is rather misguided. nowadays algebraic geometry takes place over any ring (indeed any scheme), and not just the complex numbers. The integers are just a universal and very nice ring.  By the way this answer comes from the OP...

Comment: I am very aware of modern algebraic geometry. But the fact that you can insert number theory into the language of algebraic geometry nowadays, doesn't change the fact that it is still number theory and not geometry...Indeed I have not noticed that the author of the question and the answer are the very same person. But actually that strengthens my argument, because the OP himself thinks that this is number theory and not geometry. He posted his example from number theory as an answer and wants somebody else to come up with an example from geometry.

Comment: I still deleted the comment of course, because it makes no sense given the fact that the authors are the same :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have written *elementary* number theory